# Multiple input files and output files in awk

Tags: bash, shell, awk, perl, gawk

I have a folder full of text files named 000.txt to 181.txt. How can I process all of them with the same awk script (program.awk)  and send them to their respective output files (output000.txt - output181.txt)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for f in ???.txt
do
    awk -f program.awk "$f" > "output$f"
done
```

will process all files whose names are three characters (any characters)
followed by `.txt`.  To restrict it to only files whose names
are three digits followed by `.txt`, use

```
for f in [0-9][0-9][0-9].txt
```

Comment: Do I need to type this command on the command line? for f in ???.txt
do
    awk program.awk "$f" > "output$f"
done

Comment: You can type it as four separate lines, as I showed it.  But, if you want to type it all on one line, you need to add semicolons, as in `for f in ???.txt; do awk program.awk "$f" > "output$f"; done`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll give you feedback when I get to my PC.

Comment: It worked. How about processing all the .txt files in the folder, despite the number of characters in the file names?

Comment: @G-Man; I wonder why your code would work (as the OP says); the `awk` call is lacking the `-f` switch!

Comment: @amatek; For example, `for f in *` will iterate over all files, and `for f in *.*` will iterate over all files containing a `.` in their name (files that have "extensions").

Comment: @Janis: You're right; thanks.  Obviously, I focused on the shell loop construct, and didn't pay attention to the body of the loop.  I guess the OP already knows how to run `awk` with a script in a file, and so he just silently fixed that part.  … …   … …  amatek: In case you haven't figured out the pattern yet, the wildcard (a.k.a. pattern a.k.a. "glob") for "all `.txt` files" is `*.txt`.

Comment: @G-MAN and Janis. It worked quite fine, of course with the -f part. And thanks for the update on processing all files.

Comment: @G-Man, Hi. seems like this only works in Linux. Is the command the same for Windows?

Comment: @amatek: It works fine in Cygwin.  No, of course it doesn't work in Windows Command Prompt — Unix/Linux commands generally don't.